# Problems getting gae-sessions to work in App Engine, error isn't helpful

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've installed [gae-sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions) to my development environment but it doesn't seem to be storing anything.  Here's a basic example:

```
session = get_current_session()
session.get('some_num', 3)
```

Then later on in some other function...

```
session = get_current_session()
session['some_num'] = 4
```

And here's the error I get in the console:

```
KeyError: 'some_num'
```

Not a very helpful error.  I'm pretty sure i've followed the instructions to the letter but maybe there's something i'm missing?

**edit**

appengine_config.py

```
from gaesessions import SessionMiddleware
import os

def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
    app = SessionMiddleware(app, os.urandom(32))
    return app
```

Offending code

```
class Test(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        session = get_current_session()
        if session.is_active():
            # set session['some_num'] to whatever was in there or three, otherwise
            session['some_num'] = session.get('some_num', 3) 

            # later, session['some_num'] should exist and be equal to 3 ...
            assert session['some_num'] == 3

            # ... and is actually 'settable'
            session['some_num'] = 4
        else:
            self.response.out.write("Session is NOT active")
```

.is_active() doesn't return true.

Comment: The gaesessions docs *explicitly* say do not do: `SessionMiddleware(app, cookie_key=os.urandom(32))`.  From the docs, "If you use `os.urandom()` to dynamically generate your key at runtime then any existing sessions will become junk every time your app starts up!"  (https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/blob/master/gaesessions/__init__.py#L409)

Comment: @Robert Changed the key to a random string of 64 characters ("4A21A24CBEC005D868A1DDD4CC40D831045CF193B8DACDF1B1C99ECFBE0CD4C8", to be exact) but i'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: @Don did you clear your cookies after making that change?

Comment: @Robert Yes, in both Firefox and Chrome.  I also restarted the dev server.

Comment: @Don, you might want to include the full stack trace.

Comment: @Robert Weird, I started up my dev server again to give you that stack trace but now it seems everything's working as it should.  I'm sure it's was a combination of everyone's help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code (as it stands) you don't add `some_num` to your session dictionary in the first place. Try:

```
from gaesessions import get_current_session
session = get_current_session()
if session.is_active():
    # set session['some_num'] to whatever was in there or three, otherwise
    session['some_num'] = session.get('some_num', 3) 
...

# later, session['some_num'] should exist and be equal to 3 ...
assert session['some_num'] == 3

# ... and is actually 'settable'
session['some_num'] = 4
```

Comment: Using your example and some more testing, it seems that 'session' is NOT active (.is_active() isn't true).  How do I make it active?

Comment: The session should be activated on initialization, if you have cookies enabled (See: https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/blob/master/gaesessions/__init__.py#L45).

Comment: I have the appengine_config.py file set up like the instructions say, is there anything i'm missing?

Comment: @Don How can we tell if you're missing anything if you don't show us your code?

Comment: @Nick That IS my code, in principal (saving a variable to a session, then in another function increasing the value of that variable).  I copied @MYYN's code as-is and I still got the same error, but found out that the session isn't active.  I have the appengine_config.py set up like the installation instructions say, and as far as i'm aware I haven't skipped a step on the site.  It seems like I clearly *am* missing something, though, since the session isn't active.

Comment: It's clearly not your entire code (where's appengine_config.py? where's the contents of your handler script?). We need to see _all_ the code that could be relevant, if we're to have any way of figuring out what you might be missing.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the example app ([here](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/blob/master/demo/main.py)), it appears that all sessions start off inactive, and are automatically set to active the first time you store a value to them. You should simply be able to store a value to the session with `session['foo'] = 'bar'`, and it'll automatically activate the session.

Also note that you shouldn't be generating the cookie key like that. As the docs in the [sample appengine_config.py](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/blob/master/demo/appengine_config.py) say:

```
# suggestion: generate your own random key using os.urandom(64)
# WARNING: Make sure you run os.urandom(64) OFFLINE and copy/paste the output to
# this file.  If you use os.urandom() to *dynamically* generate your key at
# runtime then any existing sessions will become junk every time you start,
# deploy, or update your app!
```